# Zonal Statistics Output Fix

Tags: python, gis, arcgis

The issue I am having is that I cannot run zonal statistics and create a table when I attempt to format the file output path for the table I want with {rounded_percent}. I'd like to have the rounded percentage value to be included in the table name. I'm not an expert with python or using it in ArcPro so I might be missing something very simple. Below I have some lines of python which I have been attempting to run in the python window on ArcPro. Please let me know if you see anything that I am doing wrong. Thanks

`# Troubleshooting
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

```
# Set input raster paths
timberland_raster = "C:\\Users\\...\\AcreageAnalysis.gdb\\Timberland_Acreage_County"
mort_pct_raster = "C:\\Users\...\\AcreageAnalysis.gdb\\MORT_PCT_AC"
county_boundary = "C:\\Users\\...\\AcreageAnalysis.gdb\\FIA_Landcover_OK_2015"
```

```
# Create binary mask for a specific percentage (for testing)
percentage = 3.700668297952402
binary_mask = Con(Raster(mort_pct_raster) == percentage, 1, 0)

# Multiply binary mask with timberland raster
affected_timberland_raster = timberland_raster * binary_mask

# Round the percentage value to three decimal places
rounded_percent = round(percentage, 3)

# Calculate zonal statistics for the affected timberland raster

# Output folder for the table
out_table = "C:\\Users\\...\\GIS\\AnalysisOutput\\tbl_{rounded_percent}.dbf".format(rounded_percent)
out_stat = ZonalStatisticsAsTable(county_boundary, "CNTY_FIPS", affected_timberland_raster, out_table, "DATA", "SUM")

print("Zonal statistics calculation completed.")


# This script works for creating a table and calculating zonal statistics on one percentage if the output table is named "tbl.dbf"
# out_table = "C:\\Users\\...\\GIS\\AnalysisOutput\\tbl.dbf"`


I have tried formatting the file output path with `"\\tbl_{0:.3f}.dbf".format(rounded_percent)` or using f-strings (as I believe they're called) like `f"C:\\Users\\...\\GIS\\AnalysisOutput\\tbl_{rounded_percent}.dbf"`
```

Answer (score 0):

From running this in ArcGIS Pro, it looks like the output table name does not allow periods. Replacing the period of the rounded percentage with another character should work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That worked, thank you, I appreciate your help

Comment: It would be helpful if you could accept this answer so as to "mark" the issue as solved, thanks!

Comment: I think it’s posted now, sorry still figuring out stackoverflow, thank you once again

Comment: No worries. What I meant was you should click on the tick mark next to the vote buttons on the answer so that it's "marked" as solved.